# How to port C# applications from windows for linux?

Tags: winforms, mono, porting

Windows.Forms library contain many bugs which effectively prevent applications from working. WinForms Designer is unable to put WebBrowser control on form.  NotifyIcon class doesn't work under LXDE (see the bugtracker of KeePass). Clipboard class is incompatible with default manager of Calculate Linux. Drag and Drop have problems in DockPanelSuite. WinForms Designer is not finished because of opacity problems. WPF was never implemented and no plans to do it.

And mono team says "we don't want to develop WinForms, because this is old technology."

How should one port desktop C# application from Windows to Linux? Rewriting it with Gtk# seems to be too hard...

What is easier - to fix mono WinForms, to implement WPF, or to rewrite all applications in the world to Gtk# ?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/picoe/Eto and https://github.com/picoe/Eto

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have already found out Mono WinForms implementation is suitable only for very simple applications. Take a look at ["Cross-Platform Desktop UIs"](http://micjames.co.uk/xplatform-desktop-ui/) blog post from Xamarin employee Mike James who summarizes available solutions:

1. **Traditional approach**
   [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601(v=vs.110).aspx) frontend on Windows, [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/) frontend on Linux and [Xamarin.Mac](http://xamarin.com/platform) on Mac OS X. IMO this is the best way to go and it may be easier than it looks if you have correctly separated business and presentation layers in your app.
2. **[XWT](https://github.com/mono/xwt)**
   XWT toolkit uses the same API and provides native look on all platforms but only a limited subset of components is implemented. Its usability for your projects depends on what components you really need.
3. **HTML frontend**
   Create HTML frontend using simple WebView component or [Awesomium HTML UI Engine](http://www.awesomium.com/). This may be a viable option in some cases but I am not sure whether it is possible to implement systray icons with this approach.
4. **[QTSHARP](https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp)**
   Open source project which aims to implement .NET bindings for multiplatform QT toolkit. I have never tried it but according to project website it seems to be in early stage and currently tested only on Windows.

BTW I am currently using WinForms for [Pkcs11Admin](http://www.pkcs11admin.net) application but I plan to use traditional approach as soon as I hit a blocker bug on any of the supported platforms.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning XWT. Looks interesting