# Porting a c# winform to linux?

Tags: c#, browser

I've been creating web browsers for school and most of my teachers are using linux.

Whilst I do have linux, I want to concentrate on programming for windows currently.

My teachers are asking me to try to port my Winform web browser so that they can use it in linux.

Is this possible? I have been using visual studio.

Thankyou in advance for any replies

Comment: Not an answer, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151350/ides-for-c-sharp-development-on-linux#151363) may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to port C# applications from windows for linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389766/how-to-port-c-sharp-applications-from-windows-for-linux)